# Multiple Mail Attachments in PHP

Tags: php, email, attachment

I was wondering if I could pick your brain about something.

I have a mail script on my site that I can use to send emails with a single attachment. Sending a single attachment works just fine.

I want to be able to send an email with multiple attachments and I am running into problems doing so.

This is the file selection box I have in the form:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment[]" multiple onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#e7e7e7'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'"/>
```

Then, when the files are selected this is the php that handles it:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) 
    {
        if(count($_FILES['attachment']['name'])>0) 
        {
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($_FILES['attachment']['name'] as $file) 
            {
                $name_of_file = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$count];
                $file_name = $guid." - ".$name_of_file;
                $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$count];
                $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'][$count];
                $file_size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$count];
                $count++;

                if ($file_size > 2048000)
                {
                    header ("refresh: 5; url=attach.php");
                    include ("header.php");
                    echo "File size is to big. Size must be no bigger than 2Mb. Please go <a href='attach.php'>back</a>";
                    include ("footer.php");
                    exit;
                }
                else
                {
                    $pics = array(".bmp", ".gif", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".png"); //5
                    $docs = array(".doc", "docx", ".odt", ".pdf", ".ppt", "pptx", ".rtf", ".txt", ".xls", "xlsx"); //10
                    $misc = array(".csv", ".htm", "html", ".php", ".pkt", ".rar", ".sql", ".xpi", ".zip"); //9

                    $base = basename($file_name);
                    $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));
                    $extension = strtolower($extension);

                    if (in_array($extension,$pics))
                    {
                        $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_PICS."/";
                    }

                    if (in_array($extension,$docs))
                    {
                        $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_DOCS."/";
                    }

                    if (in_array($extension,$misc))
                    {
                        $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_MISC."/";
                    }

                    $target = $target.$base;

                    $allowed_extensions = array(".bmp", ".csv", ".doc", "docx", ".gif", ".htm", "html",
                                                ".jpg", ".JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", ".odt", ".pdf", ".php", ".pkt", ".png", ".ppt", "pptx",
                                                ".rtf", ".sql", ".txt", ".xls", "xlsx", ".zip"
                                                );

                    if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)) 
                    {
                        $from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
                        $emailto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailto']);
                        $bcc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bcc']);
                        $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
                        $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
                        $message1 = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES);
                        if ($sendhash == 'Y')
                        {
                            $message1 .= "\n\nThe following is your unique message ID: ";
                            $message1 .= $guid;
                            $message1 .= "\n\nAttachment has been scanned for viruses and is virus free.";
                            $message1 .= "\n\nPlease make sure the first part of the file name matches the unique message ID. If it does not, please DO NOT open the file";
                            $message1 .= "\n\nTo verify the validity of the message, click the link below or copy and paste it into your browser:";
                            $message1 .= "\n\n ";
                            $message1 .= HTTP_PATH;
                            $message1 .= "verify.php?uid=";
                            $message1 .= urlencode($guid);
                            $message1 .= "\n\nPlease note, verification link expires on ";
                            $message1 .= $expirydate;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                        $message1 .= "\n\n--\nSent from Chris' Address Book";

                        foreach ($file as $files)
                        {
                        $files = $temp_name;
                        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
                        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

                        $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
                        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
                        $header .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
                        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

                        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
                        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format. \r\n";

                        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
                        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
                        $header .= $message1."\r\n";

                        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
                        $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
                        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
                        $header .= $content."\r\n";
                        }

                        if ($_POST['emailto'] == '')
                        {
                            $sqlp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".PERSON." JOIN contact on contact.personID = person.adbkid WHERE email1 = '$bcc' OR email2 = '$bcc'");
                            $num=mysql_numrows($sqlp);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $sqlp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".PERSON." JOIN contact on contact.personID = person.adbkid WHERE email1 = '$emailto' OR email2 = '$emailto'");
                            $num=mysql_numrows($sqlp);
                        }

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlp))
                        {
                            $adbkid = $row['adbkid'];
                            $id = $row['id'];
                        }

                            if ($num == 0)
                            {
                                $selfid = "EMAILSA";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $selfid = $adbkid;
                            }

                        if (mail($emailto, $subject, "", $header)) 
                        {
                            if ($sendhash == 'Y')
                            {
                                $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".EMAILS." (emailfrom, emailto, bcc, subject, message, getthedate, gettime, randhash, fileatt, fileext, showinsearch, expireit, showinverify, wasviewed, personID) VALUES ('$from', '$emailto', '$bcc', '$subject', '$message', '$getthedate', '$gettime', '$guid', '$file_name', '$extension', '$showinsearch', '$expireit', '$siv', '$wv', '$selfid')"); 
                                $lastid=mysql_insert_id();
                                $sqlr=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".HASH." (randhash) VALUES ('$guid')");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".EMAILS." (emailfrom, emailto, bcc, subject, message, getthedate, gettime, fileatt, fileext, showinsearch, expireit, showinverify, wasviewed, personID) VALUES ('$from', '$emailto', '$bcc', '$subject', '$message', '$getthedate', '$gettime', '$file_name', '$extension', '$showinsearch', '$expireit', '$siv', '$wv', '$selfid')"); 
                                $lastid=mysql_insert_id();                          
                            }
                            $sqlone = "INSERT INTO ".SENTFILES." (filename, filetype, fileext, filesize, filetempname, dateadded, timeadded, fileguid, sentmailid) VALUES ('$file_name', '$file_type', '$extension', '$file_size', '$temp_name', '$getthedate', '$gettime', '$guid', '$lastid')";
                            $expire = mysql_query("UPDATE ".EMAILS." SET showinverify = 0 WHERE expireit < CURDATE()"); 
                            if (!mysql_query($sqlone,$conn))
                            {
                                die("Error: " . mysql_error().".");
                            }

                            header ("refresh: 5; url=$url");
                            include ("header.php");
                            $ful = (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target)) ? "".$file_name." was uploaded to ".$target."" : "".$file_name.", was not uploaded. Please try a manual upload.";
                            echo "<title>Success sending email</title>";
                            echo "Your message has been successfully sent. Message details have been added to the database.<p>$ful";
                            include ("footer.php");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            header ("refresh: 5; url=$url");
                            include ("header.php");
                            echo "<title>Error sending email</title>";
                            echo "There seems to be an error sending your email.";
                            include ("footer.php");
                        }
                        exit;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header ("refresh: 5; url=attach.php");
                        include ("header.php");
                        echo "File type is not allowed. Please go <a href='attach.php'>back</a>";
                        include ("footer.php");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem I run in to is when I try to send an email this way, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/flattley/public_html/chriswilcox/cab/attach.php on line 150
```

Line 150 is this:

```
foreach ($file as $files)
```

I just don't have any idea where I am going wrong. If I don't have the foreach loop there it doesn't send or it will only send the first file.

I know I could use something like phpmailer, but I want to be able to do this on my own. I just can't see where I am going wrong.

I have tried the script on my local apache at home without mailing it and it uploads and moves multiple files just fine - as it does on my host. It's when I add the mailing option that it all goes pear shaped.

Any help you could offer would be most appreciated

Comment: there is nothing in the `$files` variable

Answer (score 0):

If you look back at your code:

```
foreach ($_FILES['attachment']['name'] as $file)
```

`$file` is already a single file name. It is not an array. As mentioned my [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

I see that in your code, you try to get the content of uploaded files. To do that, you can do something like this:

```
foreach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'] as $eachFile){
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
    $header .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format. \r\n";

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message1."\r\n";

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi, how would I use it in the context that I need it. I am assuming that the foreach loop at line 150 needs the information from the first foreach to process it here.

Comment: you have too many nested if. You need to sort this out. Check one if at a time and then, do process one at a time, like: check size, if OK, do another if until all requirement is satisfied. Next step is, loop your and build your response. Finally, echo it. That you you will ended up in a better organized code.

Comment: Hi ariefbayu, thanks for trying to answer this. I tried your change but it said that the tmp_name was empty. Also, the ifs are not the issue. I have checked and double checked them and the don't give me any problems

Comment: ifs is indeed not an issue. It just, gave me hearth attack when reading the code :|. Also, fixed the snippet

Comment: LOL. There are quite a few ifs. I just don't know how to resolve it. Using your solution either gives a foreach error or an empty tmp_name error. I just can't seem to figure it out.