# Uploading multiple files and processing them

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I just want to follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999373/multiple-mail-attachments-in-php) about multiple mail attachments.

I have had a look at various sites including [verens.com](http://verens.com/2009/12/28/multiple-file-uploads-using-html5) and [HTML 5 multi file upload with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215324/html5-multi-file-upload-with-php) on stackoverflow and I am running into a bit of an issue.

I am trying to move the file to a folder, add the contents to the database and send them as an email. This is where I am becoming unstuck. It is processing the lest file just fine, but not any of the others.

This is what I have for the code (this is from verens.com)

```
$files = array();
$fdata = $_FILES['attachment'];

if(is_array($fdata['name']))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
    {
        $files[] = array(
            $name_of_file = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i], //[$count];
            $file_name = $guid."-".$name_of_file,
            $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i], //[$count];
            $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'][$i], //[$count];
            $file_size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$i], //[$count];
        );

    }
}
else $files[] = $fdata;

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    (another snippet in the question)
}
```

When I print out the array, this is what I have:

```
Array ( 
    [attachment] => Array ( 
        [name] => Array ( 
            [0] => 96681331.jpg 
            [1] => 96681332.jpg 
            [2] => 96681333.jpg 
            [3] => 96689957.jpg 
          ) 
        [type] => Array ( 
            [0] => image/jpeg 
            [1] => image/jpeg 
            [2] => image/jpeg 
            [3] => image/jpeg 
        ) 
    [tmp_name] => Array ( 
        [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFD95.tmp 
        [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFD96.tmp 
        [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFD97.tmp 
        [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFDA8.tmp 
    ) 
    [error] => Array ( 
        [0] => 0 
        [1] => 0 
        [2] => 0 
        [3] => 0 
    ) 
    [size] => Array ( 
        [0] => 15256 
        [1] => 13672 
        [2] => 10451 
        [3] => 14356 
    )
  ) 
)
```

As you can see, it is picking up all the files in the array, it is just only processing the last one.

Here is the relevant code to satisfy those with the unhelpful comments! You get no credit for trying to make the question easy to read!

```
if ($file_size > 2048000)
{
    header ("refresh: 5; url=attach.php");
    include ("header.php");
    echo "File size is to big. Size must be no bigger than 2Mb. Please go <a href='attach.php'>back</a>";
    include ("footer.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $pics = array(".bmp", ".gif", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".png"); //5
    $docs = array(".doc", "docx", ".odt", ".pdf", ".ppt", "pptx", ".rtf", ".txt", ".xls", "xlsx"); //10
    $misc = array(".csv", ".htm", "html", ".php", ".pkt", ".rar", ".sql", ".xpi", ".zip"); //9

    $base = basename($file_name);
$extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));
$extension = strtolower($extension);

if (in_array($extension,$pics))
{
    $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_PICS."/";
}

if (in_array($extension,$docs))
{
    $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_DOCS."/";
}

if (in_array($extension,$misc))
{
    $target = "".FILES."/".FUP_MISC."/";
}

$target = $target.$base;

$allowed_extensions = array(".bmp", ".csv", ".doc", "docx", ".gif", ".htm", "html",
            ".jpg", ".JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", ".odt", ".pdf", ".php", ".pkt", ".png", ".ppt", "pptx",
            ".rtf", ".sql", ".txt", ".xls", "xlsx", ".zip"
            );

if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)) 
{
    $from = ($_POST['from']);
    $emailfrom = "bad-mailbox@chriswilcox.me.uk";
    $emailto = "bad-mailbox@chriswilcox.me.uk";
    $bcc = ($_POST['bcc']);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
    $sig = ($_POST['sig']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
    $message1 = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES);
    if ($sendhash == 'Y')
    {
        $message1 .= "\n\nThe following is your unique message ID: ";
        $message1 .= $guid;
        $message1 .= "\n\nAttachment has been scanned for viruses and is virus free.";
        $message1 .= "\n\nPlease make sure the first part of the file name matches the unique message ID. If it does not, please DO NOT open the file";
        $message1 .= "\n\nTo verify the validity of the message, click the link below or copy and paste it into your browser:";
        $message1 .= "\n\n ";
        $message1 .= HTTP_PATH;
        $message1 .= "verify.php?uid=";
        $message1 .= urlencode($guid);
        $message1 .= "\n\nPlease note, verification link expires on ";
        $message1 .= $expirydate;
    }
    else
    {
    }
    if ($signature == 'Y')
    {
        if ($sig == "")
        {
            $message1.= "\n\n--\n Sent from Chris' Address Book";
        }
        else
        {
            $message1 .= "\n\n--\n".$sig;
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }

    $file = $temp_name;
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    if ($from == 'other')
    {
        $header = "From: ".$emailfrom."\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$emailfrom."\r\n";
        $from = $emailfrom;
    }
    else
    {
        $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";                               
    }
    $header .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format. \r\n";

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message1."\r\n";

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n";

    if ($_POST['emailto'] == '')
    {
        try 
        {
            $esql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".PERSON." JOIN contact ON contact.personID = person.adbkid WHERE email1 = '$bcc' OR email2 = '$bcc'");
            $esql->execute();

            $esql->bindColumn('adbkid', $aid);
            $esql->bindColumn('pid', $pid);

            $esqlc = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".PERSON." JOIN contact ON contact.personID = person.adbkid WHERE email1 = '$bcc' OR email2 = '$bcc'");
            $esqlc->execute();

            $num = $esqlc->fetchColumn();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print '<div class="sqlerror">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $esql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".PERSON." JOIN contact ON contact.personID = person.adbkid WHERE email1 = '$emailto' OR email2 = '$emailto'");
            $esql->execute();

            $esql->bindColumn('adbkid', $aid);
            $esql->bindColumn('pid', $pid);

            $esqlc = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".PERSON." JOIN contact ON contact.personID = person.adbkid WHERE email1 = '$emailto' OR email2 = '$emailto'");
            $esqlc->execute();

            $num = $esqlc->fetchColumn();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print '<div class="sqlerror">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
        }
    }

    while ($esql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND))
    {                           
        if ($num == 0)
        {
            $selfid = "EMAILSA";
        }
        else
        {
            $selfid = $aid;
        }
    }

    if (mail($emailto, $subject, "", $header)) 
    {
        if ($sendhash == 'Y')
        {
            try
            {
                // $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".EMAILS." (emailfrom, emailto, bcc, subject, message, getthedate, gettime, randhash, fileatt, fileext, showinsearch, expireit, showinverify, wasviewed, personID) VALUES ('$from', '$emailto', '$bcc', '$subject', '$message', '$getthedate', '$gettime', '$guid', '$file_name', '$extension', '$showinsearch', '$expireit', '$siv', '$wv', '$selfid')"); 
                $hsql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".EMAILS." 
                (emailfrom, emailto, bcc, subject, message, getthedate, gettime, randhash, fileatt, fileext, showinsearch, expireit, showinverify, wasviewed, personID)
                VALUES
                (:from, :et, :bcc, :sub, :msg, :gd, :gt, :guid, :fn, :fe, :sis, :ex, :siv, :wv, :aid)");

                $hsql->bindValue(':from', $from);
                $hsql->bindValue(':et', $emailto);
                $hsql->bindValue(':bcc', $bcc);
                $hsql->bindValue(':sub', $subject);
                $hsql->bindValue(':msg', $message);
                $hsql->bindValue(':gd', $getthedate);
                $hsql->bindValue(':gt', $gettime);
                $hsql->bindValue(':guid', $guid);
                $hsql->bindValue(':fn', $file_name);
                $hsql->bindValue(':fe', $extension);
                $hsql->bindValue(':sis', $showinsearch);
                $hsql->bindValue(':ex', $expireit);
                $hsql->bindValue(':siv', $siv);
                $hsql->bindValue(':wv', $wv);
                $hsql->bindValue(':aid', $selfid);

                $hsql->execute();

                $lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();

                $sqlrh = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".HASH." (randhash) VALUES (:guid)");

                $sqlrh->bindValue(':guid', $guid);

                $sqlrh->execute();
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                print '<div class="sqlerror">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $hsql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".EMAILS." 
            (emailfrom, emailto, bcc, subject, message, getthedate, gettime, fileatt, fileext, showinsearch, expireit, showinverify, wasviewed, personID)
            VALUES
            (:from, :et, :bcc, :sub, :msg, :gd, :gt, :fn, :fe, :sis, :ex, :siv, :wv, :aid)");

            $hsql->bindValue(':from', $from);
            $hsql->bindValue(':et', $emailto);
            $hsql->bindValue(':bcc', $bcc);
            $hsql->bindValue(':sub', $subject);
            $hsql->bindValue(':msg', $message);
            $hsql->bindValue(':gd', $getthedate);
            $hsql->bindValue(':gt', $gettime);
            $hsql->bindValue(':fn', $file_name);
            $hsql->bindValue(':fe', $extension);
            $hsql->bindValue(':sis', $showinsearch);
            $hsql->bindValue(':ex', $expireit);
            $hsql->bindValue(':siv', $siv);
            $hsql->bindValue(':wv', $wv);
            $hsql->bindValue(':aid', $selfid);

            $hsql->execute();

            $lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();                            
        }
        try
        {
            $fsql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".SENTFILES." 
            (filename, filetype, fileext, filesize, filetempname, dateadded, timeadded, fileguid, sentmailid) 
            VALUES 
            (:fn, :ft, :fe, :fs, :tn, :gd, :gt, :guid, :li)");

            $fsql->bindValue(':fn', $file_name);
            $fsql->bindValue(':ft', $file_type);
            $fsql->bindValue(':fe', $extension);
            $fsql->bindValue(':fs', $file_size);
            $fsql->bindValue(':tn', $temp_name);
            $fsql->bindValue(':gd', $getthedate);
            $fsql->bindValue(':gt', $gettime);
            $fsql->bindValue(':guid', $guid);
            $fsql->bindValue(':li', $lastid);

            $fsql->execute();                               

            $expire = $conn->prepare("UPDATE ".EMAILS." SET showinverify = 0 WHERE expireit < CURDATE()");
            $expire->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print '<div class="sqlerror">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
        }
        //header ("refresh: 5; url=$url");
        include ("header.php");
        $ful = (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target)) ? "".$file_name." was uploaded to ".$target."" : "".$file_name.", was not uploaded. Please try a manual upload.";
        echo "<title>Success sending email</title>";
        echo "Your message has been successfully sent.<br/><br/>Message details have been added to the database.<br/><br/>$ful";
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        print_r($_FILES);
        include ("footer.php");
    }
    else
    {
        //header ("refresh: 5; url=$url");
        include ("header.php");
        echo "<title>Error sending email</title>";
        echo "There seems to be an error sending your email.";
        include ("footer.php");
    }
    exit;
}
else
{
    //header ("refresh: 5; url=attach.php");
    include ("header.php");
    echo "File type is not allowed. Please go <a href='attach.php'>back</a>";
    echo"<br/><br/>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    include ("footer.php");
    exit;
}
```

}

I have also tried the following code to no avail:

```
foreach ($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) 
{
    $name_of_file = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key];
    $file_name = $guid."-".$name_of_file;
    $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$key];
}
```

Like I say, it is just getting the last value in the array and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have tried the foreach just around the file array, and then also around the entire code in the pastebin and it leads to the same outcome. The confusing bit is that the files are there in the array.

Are there any obvious bits I am missing, and pointers would be most helpful.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @CBroe it's not lazy. It is for ease of reading. It is all relevant. Thanks for your unhelpful input and down vote though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set of code is working fine for me.

```
    $files = array();
    $fdata = $_FILES['attachment'];
    if(is_array($fdata['name']))
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
        {
            $name_of_file = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i];
            $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "./$name_of_file");
        }
    }
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($files);
```

All the files are uploaded in same folder. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah, it shows that they are all in the array, the issue comes to processing the files. It won't move each file or add it to the database. It will only do the last file in the array. This is where I am having issues

Comment: I have updated the code to upload all your uploaded files in same folder. Please try that

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. This works a treat at uploading them all. I just need to now figure out how to get them all in the database and sent as one email. I have enclosed the stuff to do that in the for loop, but it just goes back to the last one. Oh well, one for me to figure out. Thanks again